# Header fullcalendar customization for month display

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Good day everyone! I am a beginner javascript developer. Now I'm practicing with fullcalendar and faced such a problem.

It is necessary to display the name of the previous and next month in the header.

For example, i need to display in header "prevbut July August September nextbut".

I could not find a solution in the fuulcalendar documentation and I also could not find anything on the Internet. Perhaps someone faced with such a problem and can help me? I will be very grateful!

```
function drawCalendar() {
    const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    
    const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        locale: 'ru',
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        fixedWeekCount: false,
        firstDay: 1,
        displayEventTime: false,
        height: 700,
        
        dayMaxEventRows: true, // for all non-TimeGrid views
            views: {
                timeGrid: {
                dayMaxEventRows: 6 // adjust to 6 only for timeGridWeek/timeGridDay
                }
            },
                    
        headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev title next',
        center: '',
        right: ''
        },
       
        views: {
            dayGridMonth: {
                titleFormat: {
                    month: 'long',
                },
                dayHeaderFormat: {
                    weekday: 'long',
                }
            }
        },

        events: eventsArray,

        eventClick: function(info) {
            showEvent(info);
            // console.log(info.event.extendedProps);
            // console.log(info);
        },

        eventDidMount: function (info) {
            if (info.event.backgroundColor) {
                info.el.style.background = info.event.backgroundColor;
            }
          }
    });
    
    calendar.render();
};

drawCalendar();

let eventBlock = document.getElementById("event__modal");

function showEvent(info) {
    document.getElementById("event__overlay").classList.toggle("slidedIntoView");
    eventBlock.innerHTML = "";

    if (info.event.extendedProps.category == 'Презентация') {
        eventBlock.innerHTML += `
            <div class="event__modal">
                <div class="event__modal__top">
                    <div class="event__modal__category" style="background-color: #349EFF">${info.event.extendedProps.category}</div>
                    <img src="images/close-modal-icon.png" onclick="closeEvent()" alt="Иконка закрытия" class="close__icon">
                </div>
                <div class="event__modal__title">${info.event.title}</div>
                <div class="event__modal__spikers">${info.event.extendedProps.spikers}</div>
                <div class="event__modal__description">${info.event.extendedProps.description}</div>
                <div class="event__modal_bottom">
                    <div class="event__modal__time">Состоится ${info.event.start}</div>
                    <div class="event__modal__reminder">
                        <button class="event__modal__reminder__button">Напомнить</button>
                        <img src="images/reminder-icon.png" alt="Иконка напоминания" class="reminder__icon">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    }

    else {
        eventBlock.innerHTML += `
            <div class="event__modal">
            <div class="event__modal__top">
                    <div class="event__modal__category" style="background-color: #FFAE34">${info.event.extendedProps.category}</div>
                    <img src="images/close-modal-icon.png" onclick="closeEvent()" alt="Иконка закрытия" class="close__icon">
                </div>
                <div class="event__modal__title">${info.event.title}</div>
                <div class="event__modal__spikers">${info.event.extendedProps.spikers}</div>
                <div class="event__modal__description">${info.event.extendedProps.description}</div>
                <div class="event__modal_bottom">
                    <div class="event__modal__time">Состоится ${info.event.start}</div>
                    <div class="event__modal__reminder">
                        <button class="event__modal__reminder__button">Напомнить</button>
                        <img src="images/reminder-icon.png" alt="Иконка напоминания" class="reminder__icon">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
    }
}

function closeEvent(event) {
    document.getElementById("event__overlay").classList.remove("slidedIntoView");
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `It is necessary to display the name of the previous and next month in the header`...why? Do your users not know the order of the months in the year, and cannot predict what comes next?? Anyway no this is not possible in fullcalendar currently, and I can't see why it would be necessary. But if you want to ask for it you can go to https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: @ADyson I agree that this is a strange request, but the client wants this version of the calendar of events on his site. I was sure that I could do it through fullcalendar. It's sad that there is no solution in fullcalendar.

Comment: In my experience clients don't always make sensible requests :-). If you can explain it isn't easily possible currently, and that it's a lot of effort and expense to make a custom code for it, they may decide it's not actually worth doing, because it's such a minor enhancement (and only adds information which people should already know anyway!).

Comment: FullCalendar allows you to turn off the header toolbar by passing `headerToolbar: false`, and it's quite possible to add your own completely custom header toolbar above it that interacts with it through its JavaScript API. That would give you full control over what's displayed in the toolbar. The downside to that approach is you'd have to fully implement it yourself, so I'm not sure if you'd consider it worth that level of effort for this change.

Answer (score -1):

If it is important and necessary for someone, then I was able to find a solution:

```
function drawCalendar() {
        const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        
        const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            fixedWeekCount: false,
            firstDay: 1,
            displayEventTime: false,
            height: 700,
            
            dayMaxEventRows: true,
                views: {
                    timeGrid: {
                    dayMaxEventRows: 6 // adjust to 6 only for timeGridWeek/timeGridDay
                    }
                },
                        
            headerToolbar: {
            left: '',
            center: '',
            right: ''
            },

            views: {
                dayGridMonth: {
                    titleFormat: {
                        month: 'long',
                    },
                    dayHeaderFormat: {
                        weekday: 'long',
                    }
                }
            },

            events: eventsArray,   
            
            eventClick: function(info) {
                showEvent(info);
            },

            eventDidMount:
                function (info) {
                    if (info.event.backgroundColor) {
                        info.el.style.background = info.event.backgroundColor;
                    }
                },            
        });
        
        const currentMonthEl = document.getElementById('current-month');
        const currentDate = calendar.getDate();
        const currentMonth = calendar.formatDate(currentDate, { month: 'long' });
        currentMonthEl.textContent = currentMonth;

        const currentMoment = moment(currentDate);

        //Prev Month 2
        const prevMonthEl2 = document.getElementById('previous-month-2');
        const prevMonthMoment2 = currentMoment.clone().subtract(2, 'months');
        const prevMonthName2 = prevMonthMoment2.format('MMMM');
        prevMonthEl2.textContent = prevMonthName2;

        //Prev month 1
        const prevMonthEl1 = document.getElementById('previous-month-1');
        const prevMonthMoment1 = currentMoment.clone().subtract(1, 'months');
        const prevMonthName1 = prevMonthMoment1.format('MMMM');
        prevMonthEl1.textContent = prevMonthName1;

        //Next month 1
        const nextMonthEl1 = document.getElementById('next-month-1');
        const nextMonthMoment1 = currentMoment.add(1, 'months');
        const nextMonthName1 = nextMonthMoment1.format('MMMM');
        nextMonthEl1.textContent = nextMonthName1;

        //Next Month 2
        const nextMonthEl2 = document.getElementById('next-month-2');
        const nextMonthMoment2 = currentMoment.add(1, 'months');
        const nextMonthName2 = nextMonthMoment2.format('MMMM');
        nextMonthEl2.textContent = nextMonthName2;

        // Previous month function
        document.getElementById('prevButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
            calendar.prev();
            const currentDate = calendar.getDate();
            const currentMoment = moment(currentDate);

            // Change previous and next months
            const prevMonthMoment1 = currentMoment.clone().subtract(1, 'months');
            const prevMonthName1 = prevMonthMoment1.format('MMMM');
            prevMonthEl1.textContent = prevMonthName1;

            const prevMonthMoment2 = currentMoment.clone().subtract(2, 'months');
            const prevMonthName2 = prevMonthMoment2.format('MMMM');
            prevMonthEl2.textContent = prevMonthName2;

            const nextMonthMoment1 = currentMoment.add(1, 'months');
            const nextMonthName1 = nextMonthMoment1.format('MMMM');
            nextMonthEl1.textContent = nextMonthName1;

            const nextMonthMoment2 = currentMoment.add(1, 'months');
            const nextMonthName2 = nextMonthMoment2.format('MMMM');
            nextMonthEl2.textContent = nextMonthName2;

            const currentMonth = calendar.formatDate(currentDate, { month: 'long' });
            currentMonthEl.textContent = currentMonth;
        });

        // Next month function
        document.getElementById('nextButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
            calendar.next();
            const currentDate = calendar.getDate();
            const currentMoment = moment(currentDate);

            // Change previous and next months
            const prevMonthMoment1 = currentMoment.clone().subtract(1, 'months');
            const prevMonthName1 = prevMonthMoment1.format('MMMM');
            prevMonthEl1.textContent = prevMonthName1;

            const prevMonthMoment2 = currentMoment.clone().subtract(2, 'months');
            const prevMonthName2 = prevMonthMoment2.format('MMMM');
            prevMonthEl2.textContent = prevMonthName2;

            const nextMonthMoment1 = currentMoment.add(1, 'months');
            const nextMonthName1 = nextMonthMoment1.format('MMMM');
            nextMonthEl1.textContent = nextMonthName1;

            const nextMonthMoment2 = currentMoment.add(1, 'months');
            const nextMonthName2 = nextMonthMoment2.format('MMMM');
            nextMonthEl2.textContent = nextMonthName2;

            const currentMonth = calendar.formatDate(currentDate, { month: 'long' });
            currentMonthEl.textContent = currentMonth;
        });            
        calendar.render();
    };
```

drawCalendar();

Comment: Is this your solution? If so, please explain how it solved your problem and what code you changed. See also [answer]. Otherwise, people reading it have to guess, or spend a lot of time reading your code to work it out, which is not very helpful.

Comment: Or perhaps this is not an answer at all, and in fact you intended to add some information to your question? If so please click the "edit" button underneath your question, to do that. You have posted this as if it was an answer. Stackoverflow does not work like a traditional discussion forum. I can see from your profile that you have not taken the [tour] (which was offered to you when you registered your account) - please do that so that you understand the basics of how the site works.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The "Post Answer" button should be used only for complete answers to the question.